# How to scan networks with WvDial?

Tags: networking, debian, usb-modem, wvdial

I am using WvDial to scan available networks with these commands:

```
Init1 = AT+COPS=?
Baud=460800
Modem = /dev/ttyACM0
```

Wvdial tries the scan-commands but it seems like it does not wait long enough for a response, because it returns after 3-5 seconds and says „Modem not responding“. How can I make WvDial wait longer?

Calling „AT+CSQ“ returns 22 - so the signal is good. And I can also call my Internet provider and get Internet connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can get available networks by using a different solution:

First I open a terminal and issue this command:

```
# tr -s „\n“ < /dev/ttyACM0
```

Then I open another terminal and issue this command:

```
# echo -e „AT+COPS=?\r“ > /dev/ttyACM0
```

After about 30 seconds the first terminal will return a response with the available networks.